# <source_model> for customer group not working

Tags: php, magento

I am building magento module. I need to show available customer groups in admin configuration.
I used following code in system.xml to get available customer groups,

```
 <customergroup translate="label">
      <label>Select Customer Group can view Pricing/Purchase Product</label>
      <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
      <source_model>customer/group</source_model>
      <sort_order>1</sort_order>
      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
      <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
      <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
 </customergroup>
```

This code produces error that,

> **Invalid method Mage_Customer_Model_Group::toOptionArray(**

Is there any method to find Model for Customer groups?

Comment: try with `<source_model>customer/customer_attribute_source_group</source_model>`

Comment: Marius above did't worked, I've tried this adminhtml/system_config_source_customer_group, it worked,but its showing --Please Select-- as first option, can we able to remove first option?